# migrating from JBoss 4.2.3 to 5.1 - module listed in application.xml is not a recognized deployment

Tags: deployment, jboss, war, ear

I have an ear which currently works fine when deployed in JBoss 4.2.3. I am attempting to migrate to JBoss 5.0.1 but am getting the error 'classpath module listed in application.xml is not a recognized deployment'.

Below is the struture of my ear:

```
              MyApp
                |       
                +- classpath
                |       
                +- lib
                |   |
                |   +- A.jar
                |   +- B.jar
                |   +- C.jar
                |
                +- META-INF 
                |   |
                |   +- application.xml
                |   +- jboss-app.xml
                |
                +- D.jar
                |
                *- E.jar
                |
                +- F.jar
                |
                +- myApp.war
                    |
                    +- WEB-INF
                    |
                    +- ....
```

Below is what I have in my application.xml:

```
<application>
  <display-name>MyApp</display-name>
  <module>
    <java>classpath</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <java>lib/A.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <java>lib/B.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <java>D.jar</java>
  </module>

  ...      

  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>myApp.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/WEB-INF</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

As mentioned the current structure of my ear and the application.xml outlined above, all works fine in JBoss 4.2.3. However, when I deploy this is JBoss 5.1.0 it appears not to like the 'classpath' module defined in the application.xml.

Below is the full stack trace occuring:

```
17:02:09,767 WARN  [HDScanner] Scan failed
    org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Exception determining structure: AbstractVFSDeployment(MyApp.ear)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
        at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructuralDeployers.determineStructure(AbstractStructuralDeployers.java:85)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineStructure(MainDeployerImpl.java:1004)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineDeploymentContext(MainDeployerImpl.java:440)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:390)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:300)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.addDeployment(MainDeployerAdapter.java:86)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:344)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:255)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error determining structure: MyApp.ear
        at org.jboss.deployment.EARStructure.determineStructure(EARStructure.java:293)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.StructureDeployerWrapper.determineStructure(StructureDeployerWrapper.java:73)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.doDetermineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:196)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.determineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:221)
        at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructuralDeployers.determineStructure(AbstractStructuralDeployers.java:77)
        ... 16 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: classpath module listed in application.xml is not a recognized deployment, .ear: MyApp.ear
        at org.jboss.deployment.EARStructure.determineStructure(EARStructure.java:277)
        ... 20 more
```

I'm tearing my hair out with this one! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is that JBoss 5.x automatically adds any JARs in `lib` to the EAR's classpath, so you don't actually need to specify them in the `application.xml`.

For your `classpath` directory, you'll have to rename that to `classpath.jar`, and then 5.x should accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the response skaffman. You were right, classpath as a folder is rejected. I moved the property and xml files contained within it to my war and JBoss 5 accepted the application.xml. I've still got a few jar conflicts to resolve but I'll try and work through them. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

What is the

```
 <module>
    <java>classpath</java>
  </module>
```

You are referring to in the application.xml? This does not look like a valid jar archive name. Try removing this entry and redeploy.

Comment: JBoss 4.x was happy to let you add directories to the `applicatiom.xml`. v5 not so much.

Comment: Yes, JBoss 5 requires that the property and xml files contained within my classpath folder need to be moved into a jar. I've moved them into my war and it's fixed the problem! Onto the next issue...